# Enable App Sandboxing cause application not to save files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.3

I have an application that generates bar codes, once generated the user can save the code as png, jpeg etc ... it was working fine before apple introduces sandboxing, once i enable it the application doesn't save the files, it only does that when it is disabled, i've tried playing around with access permissions that they have under the sandbox in xcode i've tried enabling everything under it too but nothing seems to be working to solve the problem, sop not sure what else can i try, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

my project is saved inside the documents folder if that will make any difference.

the application is signed, tried self signed and the code generated through apple developer program.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you use an `NSSavePanel`, or `NSOpenPanel`, because only those two objects can explicitly give you access to user-selected files.

And make sure that under the entitlements selection that you have read/write access to user selected files:

[image]

If you're already doing these two steps, and it still doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, am using NSSavePanel and al tried enabling everything and giving all the folders read/write too but nothing is working, any other suggestions?

Comment: @incoe sorry about the late response. Have you gotten it working yet? If not, could we see the code where you handle saving files?

Comment: no probs sure i'll host the file on pastebin for 30 days just in case were busy http://pastebin.com/w46bzks2 its from line 125